# Differentiability of $\sqrt{\frac{2x^4+2y^4+2z^4+3x^2y^2+3y^2z^2}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Let $$f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{\frac{2x^4+2y^4+2z^4+3x^2y^2+3y^2z^2}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}}.$$

Is $f\in C^2(\mathbb R^3\setminus\{0\})$?

My thoughts: According to wolfram alpha we have $f(x,y,z)\in[1,\sqrt{2}]$. The only points where $f$ wouldn't be differentiable are given by the roots of the fraction. Everywhere else is the function $f$ obviously differentiable. Since $f\geq1$ everyhwere, we don't have any roots and the function $f$ is everywhere differentiable.

Then I've tried to consider the range of the partial derivatives to see if they are continuous and differentiable, but since I can't find the range and it's pretty difficult to find all the roots, I am asking myself if there is a easier way to verifiy $f\in C^2(\mathbb R^3\setminus\{0\})$.

My question: How can you verify $f\in C^2(\mathbb R^3\setminus\{0\})$ easily?

Comment: All the monomials of the numerator of the fraction are squares, so they are positive everywhere, and vanish only at the origin. On a side note, why have you found the range of $f$ to check if it is differentiable?

Comment: @EdmundoMartins Since I want to know if $f\in C^2$, what about the second derivative? This is what we get from wolfram alpha for $\partial_x$: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+sqrt((2x%5E4%2B2y%5E4%2B2z%5E4%2B3x%5E2y%5E2%2B3y%5E2z%5E2)%2F((x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2)%5E2)) So it should be the same argument, shouldn't it? And I thought about finding the roots of $\partial_x$ (similar to the first derivative due to the square root), which according to wolfram we don't need to!

Comment: Change to spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: In fact $f$ is $C^\infty$ on this domain.
To see this, note the numerator is a positive polymomial raised to the $1/2$ power. The denominator is a positive polynomial on this domain.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Changing to spherical coordinates

$$
x = r\sin\theta\cos\phi\\
y = r \sin\theta\sin\phi\\
z = r\cos\theta
$$

we obtain after simplifications

$$
f(x,y,z) \equiv g(\theta,\phi)
$$

so $f(x,y,z)$ is not continuous at $(0,0,0)$ but $g(\theta,\phi)\in \mathbb{C}^{\infty}$ then in $\mathbb{C}^3\setminus \{0\}$ we have using the chain rule

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial\theta}\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x_i}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial\phi}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_i}
$$

and those operations are well defined and continuous for $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}> 0$

etc.

A glimpse at $g(\theta,\phi)$

[image]

Comment: The question is whether $f$ is twice continuously differentiable away from $0.$  Does this answer somehow address that?